# AngularJS $promise used with NgResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I came across promises as I am going through my journey on learning AngularJS and it has been good so far. Now, I wanted to learn more about using AngularJS optional library resource.js. However, I came across examples that confused me a lot. For example, the promise skeleton is basically like this example.

```
//post method to server
$http.post('api/school',newStudent).then(fetchStudents).then(function(response){    
   //do something
}, function(error){
   //do something
});
```

and another example like this assuming we have a List factory

```
List.save(self.newStudent).$promise.then(fetchStudents).then(function(){
        self.newStudent = {};
});
```

So my question is why the use of $promise? What is the use of it? It was not really explained in the book I am using and I am confuse on when to use it or not. Any clear explanation will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can become a promise ninja after reading this:
http://www.webdeveasy.com/javascript-promises-and-angularjs-q-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their
>   return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing

Promises provide a simpler alternative for executing, composing, and managing asynchronous operations when compared to traditional callback-based approaches. They also allow you to handle asynchronous errors using approaches that are similar to synchronous try/catch.

Read more about it at :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

http://haroldrv.com/2015/02/understanding-angularjs-q-service-and-promises/

http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls